# How to show to users only survey that he didn't answered to?

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

So I have this problem. I have few surveys and I want to show that surveys to users, but here is a tricky part. There can be multiple surveys, so I had to make more to more relation. But one user can have only one answer per survey. I want to show to user only surveys that he dind't answered to. Can someone tell how to execute query, or maybe how to fix table stucture or similar?

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly straightforward.  These two queries are pretty much equivalent:

```
select survey.survey_id
from survey
where not exists (select 1 from survey_users where survey_users.survey_id=survey_id and survey_users.user_id=?)

select survey.survey_id
from survey
left join survey_users on survey_users.survey_id=survey_id and survey_users.user_id=?
where survey_users.survey_id is null
```